# Как отследить используемые Pug файлы

Tags: javascript, gulp, pug

Использую свою библиотеку блоков в pug миксинах, каждый блок в отдельной папке. Собираю с помощью gulp. Есть ли способ отслеживать в gulp, какие миксины были использованы на странице чтобы подтянуть их зависимости?